# SQL Delete with Multiple Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have some what of a challenging delete statement that I need help with. I'm trying to delete multiple duplicate records with multiple joins on the same table.

Here is an example of my data

#### versionid(PK) FileID(FK) Version    DeleteDate  DeleteIndicator

```
   1              1         1      12/01/2003        1
   2              1         1      12/02/2003        1 
   3              1         1         null           0
   4              2         2      01/02/2004        1
   5              2         2      01/03/2005        1
   6              2         2      01/03/2006        1
```

The data I need to delete is all duplicate data matched by the FileId and the Version where DeleteDate is less than 04/01/2011 and the DeleteIndicator is = 1. But, I need to keep the highest VersionID out of the duplicate data that has the same FileId and Version

After the delete I would have this remaining:

#### versionid(PK) FileID(FK) Version   DeleteDate  DeleteIndicator

```
  2              1         1      12/02/2003        1 
  3              1         1         null           0
  6              2         2      01/03/2006        1
```

I have a select w/ multiple joins that would give me the above records. I just don't know how to turn that into a delete statement. Here is my select statement.

```
SELECT  t.VersionID ,
    t.FileID ,
    t.version ,
    COUNT(*) ,
    t.DeleteDate ,
    t.DeleteIndicator
FROM    tblFileVersions t
    JOIN ( SELECT   VersionID ,
                    FileID ,
                    MAX(VersionID) AS MaxVersion ,
                    DeleteDate ,
                    DeleteIndicator
           FROM     tblFileVersions
           GROUP BY VersionID ,
                    FileID ,
                    DeleteDate ,
                    DeleteIndicator
         ) x ON t.FileID = x.FileID
WHERE   t.DeleteDate < '2011/04/01'
    AND t.DeleteIndicator = 1
    AND t.VersionID < MaxVersion
GROUP BY t.VersionID ,
    t.FileID ,
    t.version ,
    t.DeleteDate ,
    t.DeleteIndicator ,
    Version
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
```

All I need to do is take what I have and make it a delete statement. Sorry if my text format is all screwed up this is the first time I have posted on here. Any help would be great thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpliest way to simple do that:

```
DELETE FROM tblFileVersions 
WHERE VersionID NOT IN (SELECT  t.VersionID
FROM    tblFileVersions t
    JOIN ( SELECT   VersionID ,
                    FileID ,
                    MAX(VersionID) AS MaxVersion ,
                    DeleteDate ,
                    DeleteIndicator
           FROM     tblFileVersions
           GROUP BY VersionID ,
                    FileID ,
                    DeleteDate ,
                    DeleteIndicator
         ) x ON t.FileID = x.FileID
WHERE   t.DeleteDate < '2011/04/01'
    AND t.DeleteIndicator = 1
    AND t.VersionID < MaxVersion
GROUP BY t.VersionID ,
    t.FileID ,
    t.version ,
    t.DeleteDate ,
    t.DeleteIndicator ,
    Version
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Well done, thanks guys this worked. I actually had to change the "Where VersionID NOT IN (MY QUERY) to IN (MY QUERY) because I was grabbing all the one I wanted to delete. ONCE AGAIN THANKS!!!!

Comment: You were in the near, it was not a big help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use your query as subquery but select only one PK field versionID:

```
Delete from tblFileVersions where 
versionid NOT IN (select t.VersionID from tblFileVersions t Join...CONTINUE YOUR QUERY HERE......)
```

Comment: I'm confused. Do I take out my t.fileid and t.version, count(*) before my t alias?

Comment: You should delete all rows with versionId's NOT FROM your query so just use your query to output only versionId's without other fields.